# Django Migrations Tree Issues - Deployment PythonAnywhere

Tags: django, github, deployment, migration

I have been having this issue when managing Django migrations on deployment, and I would like to know what approach should I take:

I am developing an application using Django, and I am using PythonAnywhere to deploy the web app. I am using SQLite as the database. I understand the Django migrations work like a tree or a sequence (001, 002).

Every time I make a change in a field locally, it works fine because the tree has been saved and the sequence has not changed. But when deploying the changes through GitHub (having deployed the web app and calling the `migrations` and `migrate` command, which creates another migrations files and sequence), I usually get an error indicating that the migration tree is broken. So I have to go to the app's migration folder, delete them, and call the `migrations` and `migrate` commands again.

This is causing me a lot of problems, as I do not want to mess with schema of the database and lose the information.

It is just me or anyone else is having this issue the migrations tree, not only on PythonAnywhere but on others servers?

Thank you!

Comment: You should commit the migrations to mantain the consistency (you shouldn't commit the database though).  See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/

Comment: Hello @JorgeArmandoMolanoPrada did you added **migrations/** directory inside your **.gitignore** file ?

Comment: @AnkitTiwari,  In that case, If multiple developers are pushed their local migration files into the git repository, we are again seeing errors like "multiple leaf nodes in the migration graph". How do we solve this ?. FYI, developer1 might not know the tree structure of developer2 and developer3 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys! @Ankit Tiwari, not I did not as the Django documentation says that it is important to keep the migrations files on deployment as @caseneuve recommended. Even thought I read somewhere that on the server side is not necessary to call the makemigrations command, just the migrate as the migrations files already exist; so I try it and so far it is not giving me more errors. Thanks for the answers.